# Faster way to apply a function to every pair of columns in pandas data frame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy-ndarray

I am trying to apply some function on every possible pair of columns in a data frame. The iteration method works, but since the data frame is huge it takes up a lot of time. My data frame has a size of around 10,000 columns and 1000 rows.
Is there a faster way of doing this. Given below is a toy example of the same.

**TOY EXAMPLE**

My function is something like this:

```
def foo(x,y):
    if ['alpha','beta'] == df[[x,y]]:
        print(x,y)

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7,8], [9,10,11,12]])
for i in df.columns:
   for j in df.columns:
       foo(i,j)
```

I have also tried loop comprehension and itertools.combinations, but it is also taking a lot of time.
`z = [foo(i,j) for i,j in itertools.combinations(df.columns,2)]`

My function is exactly the same. It checks if 3-4 rows are present in the pair of columns and writes the column information to a file.

I tried using numpy matrices instead of data frame, but did not achieve any significant time improvement. All of the above are working but takes a lot of time (obviously due to the huge size of the data frame). Hence I need some help in optimizing the time.

Any suggestions regarding the same would be highly appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: It really depends on the real-life function, can you vectorize it? what is the output?

Comment: Give an example of a real function and we can help you

Comment: @mozway The real function is exactly the same as given. It checks if certain rows are in the columns and writes the column information to file.

Comment: do you need to iterate over all pairs of columns in your dataframe's 10,000 columns, or are you working with a particular pair?

Comment: I need to iterate over every pair. The problem is finding pairs of columns that satisfy certain conditions. It is about creating a graph with the columns as vertices. There is an edge if the columns satisfy the conditions. I have to print the list of edges in the graph

Comment: @mozway, I did think about vectorizing it. But didn't get too much idea on how to do the same.